# Make an if with ping and ttl

Tags: c#, ping, ttl

I want to run in my code a function that checks if the unit is online and also if the **TTL** is less then **250**

but I didn't find where to see the **TTL**

**Code:**

```
string data   = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
int timeout   = 1500;

PingReply reply = p.Send(IP,timeout,buffer);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Online.Add(IP)
}
```

What is the option for seeing the **TTL**?

Comment: `reply.Options.Ttl`?

Answer (score 0):

Its a surprisingly uncommon thing to do when you start programming, but the first place you should look when you want to know something is the documentation.

[Ping Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/%E2%80%A6%20and%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144956(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Ping.Send Method (IPAddress, Int32, Byte[], PingOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144955(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Attempts to send an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo
>   message with the specified data buffer to the computer that has the
>   specified IPAddress and receive a corresponding ICMP echo reply
>   message from that computer. This overload allows you to specify a
>   time-out value for the operation and control fragmentation and
>   Time-to-Live values for the ICMP echo message packet.

[PingOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Properties**

> **Ttl**    Gets or sets the number of routing nodes that can forward the
>   Ping data before it is discarded.

[PingOptions.Ttl Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingoptions.ttl(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the number of routing nodes that can forward the Ping
>   data before it is discarded.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> As gateways and routers transmit packets through a network, they
>   decrement the current Time-to-Live (TTL) value found in the packet
>   header. If the TTL value reaches zero, the packet is deemed
>   undeliverable and is discarded. This option is useful if you want to
>   test the number of routers and gateways used to transmit the data.

**Example**

```
public static string PingHost(string host)
{
    //string to hold our return messge
    string returnMessage = string.Empty;

    //IPAddress instance for holding the returned host
    IPAddress address = GetIpFromHost(ref host);

    //set the ping options, TTL 128
    PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);

    //create a new ping instance
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    //32 byte buffer (create empty)
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];

    //set the ping options, TTL 128
    PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);

    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(address, 1000, buffer, pingOptions);

    if (!(pingReply == null))
    {
       switch (pingReply.Status)
       {
          case IPStatus.Success:
                returnMessage = string.Format("Reply from {0}: bytes={1} time={2}ms TTL={3}", 
                                   pingReply.Address, 
                                   pingReply.Buffer.Length, 
                                   pingReply.RoundtripTime, 
                                   pingReply.Options.Ttl);
                break;
          case IPStatus.TimedOut:
                returnMessage = "Connection has timed out...";
                break;
          default:
                returnMessage = string.Format("Ping failed: {0}", pingReply.Status.ToString());
                break;
       }
    }
    else
       returnMessage = "Connection failed for an unknown reason...";

...
```

Comment: this line--->   PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);    what does it mean? that the max is 128?